# Will this monitor/pc/speaker configuration work?

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

Will this monitor/pc/speaker configuration work?

-I want to upgrade my 19" PC monitor, to either a 24" or 27" inch one.

-I use the monitor for my PC, as well as my PS3.

-Selection of monitors with 2 HDMI ports  is limited, so I'm considering a monitor with 1 HDMI, and 1 DVI.

-Also, speakers on monitors seem to be lousy, so I will keep my current speakers (they are your average $20 speakers from walmart, that plug into the audio port in the PC..)

My plan is to:

-Connect the PS3 (via HDMI) to the monitor.

-Connect my PC (via DVI) to the monitor, and also connect the audio port, from my motherboard, to the monitor.

-Connect my speakers to the monitor, so that they output the sound (from either the PS3's HDMI source, or the audio source from the PC).

So that means, I need a monitor that has:

-HDMI input, DVI input

-an audio-in port

-an audio-out port (for the speakers)

Does such a monitor exist?  If so, can someone please link me to one, preferably from newegg.com, where it clearly has all 4 ports?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Shopping recommendations are not within the scope of Superuser. Please read the FAQ. http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: And I'd add that it sounds less like you want a PC monitor and more like you might want a small television that'll take input from your PC.

Comment: Such monitors exist, this is not the place for recommendations I'm afraid.

Comment: @EBGreen, how is this a shopping recommendation question? Just because it happens to have a dollar-sign in it (which doesn’t even have anything to do with the monitor in question)? The question is clearly asking if there are any monitors that have HDMI and DVI as well as audio in and out connectors (so that external speakers can be attached to it). You can safely just ignore the dollar-sign and either link to such a monitor or demonstrate that no such thing exists.

Comment: @Shinrai, I don’t see anything about a tuner or a requirement of watching TV. He is just looking for a typical monitor with HDMI and DVI ports and built-in speakers, but also with audio out connectors.

Comment: @Synetech - My point was that if you want a display device that supports HDMI style audio with decent sound quality, it probably makes more sense to buy a television (unless you want 2560x1600 or something).  (And this is a shopping recommendation, he's just asking us to recommend a product.  This sort of thing usually only flies if it's asking for something incredibly niche.)

Comment: But his points is that he doesn’t want the audio from the monitor, he wants to use external speakers. And it’s not shopping if he is simply asking if such a monitor exists. He never used the term recommend, and don’t forget, you are all free to edit it to make it more palatable.

Comment: Thank you Synetech for making my point clear, I appreciate it.

Comment: The community position has traditionally been that "I can't find <product x>" and "Which <product x> should I get" are basically the same question - that is, they're asking for a product that fulfills a specific list of criteria; a shopping recommendation.  They're off-topic because they aren't helpful into perpetuity.  These questions are typically only allowed if <product x> is something unusual or rare that would require extreme expertise to find (say, "I need a matrix switcher that supports 16 VIVO video inputs and makes me breakfast in bed", the sort of thing Google isn't helpful for.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a basic Philips monitor and have it set up almost exactly as you describe.
I use the headphone socket to plug in my PC speakers. I actually use a splitter also connect the PC speakers to my PC.

I think any monitor with HDMI and speakers will have a headphone socket and do the job. The only thing I don't like is the touch-sensitve buttons that make switching a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just plug the external speakers into your audio card and forgo the monitor altogether (thus leaving it its real task that its good at: video)?

For the PS3 audio cables, it depends on the speakers you get. If they have an HDMI connector, you can use an [HDMI splitter](http://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_nkw=hdmi%20splitter%20-dvi%20-switch&_sop=15). If not, you can use an [HDMI to RCA/Optical adapter](http://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_nkw=hdmi%20rca%20audio%20-component%20-rgb&_sop=15) or the [RCA cable that came with it](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071017233022AARlrYL).

It may not be quite as convenient as having all the ports built into the monitor, but it does give you more flexibility in your setup (and is much cheaper too).

Comment: Where does sound from the PS3 go (carried in the HDMI cable)?

Comment: @BenVoigt, added an explanation.